# Calling a method with a return type

Tags: java, return-type

In the method below (Not currently finished), I am confused as to why I am able to call `divide(a, left, pIndex, iVal)` without assigning it to an integer or printing the result because the return type of the method is int.

Same applies to `divide(a, pIndex + 1, right, iVal);`

```
public static int divide(int[] a, int left, int right, int iVal) {
        int value = 0;
        if (left < right) {
            int pIndex = sort(a, left, right);

            if (pIndex == iVal) {
                return a[iVal];
            }
            else if (pIndex > iVal) {

               } 
               divide(a, left, pIndex, iVal);
               divide(a, pIndex + 1, right, iVal);
           }
           return -1; // stub
       }
```

Comment: I think you are getting confused by [Recursion](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/).

Comment: Callers are never required to store or display the result of a method call.

Comment: Just because something returns a value doesn't mean you have to do anything with it...

Comment: Java doesn't force you to do anything with a method's return value. You're allowed to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Methods may be called in any programming language *without* assigning the return value to a variable. 
But what if the type is a `void`? Then with your reasoning, what type should you assign it to? 
Java(and most other languages) will be perfectly fine if you do not assign the return value to a variable. However, you *cannot* use
`1+1;`
or
`433782.382;`
Try these yourself and you will see that they will not compile. However, Java(and most other programming languages) will override method calls so that they do not have to assign their return value to a variable. 
(In the error, it says that 1+1 is not a statement. However, a method call *is* a statement.)

Comment: The "Java Language" does not "override" method calls so that they do not have to assign their return value to a variable, it just doesn't get assigned.